# Merge two arrays of Objects by value returned from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

***Problem***

I need to merge two arrays that are returned from MongoDB by value, however all of the methods I've tried that work with regular javascript arrays aren't working properly.  Your help would be greatly appreciated

***Arrays***

```
array1 = [ { _id: 5c6c7132f9bf4bdab9c906ff,
    user: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d },
  { _id: 5c6ccd6d3a0dc4e4951c2bee,
    user: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e } ]

array2 = users [ { _id: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d,
    info: { name: 'John', city: 'New York' } },
  { _id: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e,
    info: { name: 'Paneer', city: 'San Fran' } } ]
```

***Desired Result***

```
mergedArray = [ { _id: 5c6c7132f9bf4bdab9c906ff,
    user: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d,
    info: { name: 'John', city: 'New York' } } ,
  { _id: 5c6ccd6d3a0dc4e4951c2bee,
    user: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e, 
    info: { name: 'Paneer', city: 'San Fran' } } ]
```

***What I've tried***

1. _.merge from lodash
2. _.map & _.extend from lodash
3. A variety of vanilla javascript .map functions that

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over `array1` and get the related `info` data from the `array2` with [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const array1 = [
  {_id: '5c6c7132f9bf4bdab9c906ff', user: '5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d'},
  {_id: '5c6ccd6d3a0dc4e4951c2bee', user: '5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e'}
];

const array2 = [
  {
    _id: '5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d',
    info: { name: 'John', city: 'New York' }
  },
  {
    _id: '5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e',
    info: { name: 'Paneer', city: 'San Fran' }
  }
];

let merged = array1.map(
    o => ({...o, info: array2.find(({_id}) => _id === o.user).info})
);

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```